# String variable assignment gives pointer error

Tags: c, cs50

```
string reading_lev(int a, int b, int c)
{
    float L = (a / b) * 100;
    float S = (c / b) * 100;
    float index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;
    if (round(index) <= 16 && round(index) >= 1)
    {
        string val = printf("Grade %f", index);
    }
    else if (round(index) > 16)
    {
        string val = printf("Grade 16+");
    }
    else
    {
        string val = printf("Before Grade 1");
    }
    return val
}
```

The error is in the first *if* block. There are cs50 libraries involved.

> error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'string' (aka 'char *') with an expression of type 'int' [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]

Comment: `string val = printf(...)`? `printf` returns an `int`, you need to allocate space and then use [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) to return a string.

Comment: `val` only exists until the closing brace `}`, so the `return` should also be generating an error.

Comment: @user3386109 and missing `;` in return statement, too.

Answer (score 4):

The error message is self explanatory.

[`printf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) returns an `int`, you cannot assign it to variable of type `char*`.

That said, you have multiple other issues:

- The return statement uses a block scope variable, which is out of it's scope.
- The return statement is missing a `;` - syntax error.

To fix the code what you need to do is:

- Allocate a buffer long enough to hold the final output. (Define a pointer and use allocated memory using `malloc()` or family, of sufficient size)
- Use `sprintf()` to populate the memory with the output you need.
- Return the pointer.
- Once you're done using it, `free()` the returned pointer.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is really basic but I am new. How can printf() return an int? Isn't everything in " "?

Comment: @KushagraSharma Read the linked man page.What printf prints and what is returns are not the same.

Comment: @kaylum Updated.

Comment: @KushagraSharma One of the first things you need to do as a C programmer is find the documentation. On unix systems, you can open a terminal window and type `man 3 printf` to get the documentation for `printf`. On windows, the documentation is online by searching `msdn printf`. You might also want to invest in a [good reference book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @user3386109 Its 2 in the morning where I live X( could you please briefly tell me how to fix my code? It would really help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *sprintf* to save the formatted data to a string. Be aware that you need a buffer big enough to save the string.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

Comment: Its 2 in the morning where I live X( could you please briefly tell me how to fix my code? It would really help me.